# How to create dotnet core project with lower version in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, sdk, asp.net-core-mvc

I with this command:

```
dotnet new mvc
```

creating an ASP.NET Core MVC project in VS Code, but since SDK version 7 is installed on my computer, the project is created with version 7.

How should I create a project with .NET Core 3.1 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parameter `--framework` for specifying the version. Ex - if you want to build in .NET 6.0. The command will be `dotnet new mvc --framework net6.0`

Comment: What about version 3.1?

Comment: You can use `--framework netcoreapp3.1`

Answer (score 0):

In your .csproj file, you can set `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>`